# Define column name which only takes 10 digit number in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following code in for a SQL TABLE

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_1](
    [ID] [int] NULL,
    [StudentID] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Address] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [Phone] [nvarchar](10) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

But I can insert any value for StudentID. I want to insert 10 digit number, if it is less/greater then 10 digit it shouldn't take the value. Can anyone help me with this since I am new to SQL. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want `StudentId` to be ten digits, you can define a `check` constraint.  In SQL Server, this would look like:

```
alter table table_1 add constraint chk_table_1_student_id
    check (student_id like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]');
```

If you don't like counting expressions in strings, you can also specify:

```
alter table table_1 add constraint chk_table_1_student_id
    check (len(student_id) = 10 and student_id not like '%[^0-9]%');
```

That is, it has a length of 10 and no non-digit characters.